# Windows Phone force page to reload

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing application page with Hub control for Windows Phone 8.1. I needed to have dynamic number of hub sections. I found solution [there](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2013/11/13/Databinding-with-the-Windows-81-Hub-control.aspx). It works pretty well. But I have an issue with it.

### XAML

```
<Hub x:Name="newsHub" x:Uid="Hub"
   helpers:HubBinder.DataSource="{Binding}"
   helpers:HubBinder.HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HubSectionHeaderTemplate}"
   helpers:HubBinder.SectionTemplate="{StaticResource HubSectionTemplate}">
</Hub>
```

When I change page's DataContext, it does not affect newsHub to update. I need solution to fix that issue in binding or workaround like page reload or something.

Please help!

Comment: You said `When I change page's DataContext`, do you change the all `DataContext` object or its list content? If you just change the content as the code it won't update hubs, or I believe it will.

Comment: @SimonChan, I am changing page's datacontext, and, as far as I have binding, I expect that my hub would be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to force binding update?

```
newsHub.GetBindingExpression(HubBinder.DataSourceProperty).UpdateTarget();
```